# How to override menu Item?

Tags: 7, routes

I am using [entity_translation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) for translating node titles. And with this Translate tab appears on node view like in screenshot.

[image]

I am trying to override titles and access permissions for this menu tab and found that its coded in **/sites/all/modules/entity_translation/entity_translation.node.inc** like below:

```
/**
 * Node-specific menu alterations.
 */
function entity_translation_node_menu_alter(&$items, $backup) {
  if (isset($backup['node'])) {
    $item = $backup['node'];
    // Preserve the menu router item defined by other modules.
    $callback['page callback'] = $item['page callback'];
    $callback['file'] = $item['file'];
    $callback['module'] = $item['module'];
    $access_arguments = array_merge(array(1, $item['access callback']), $item['access arguments']);
  }
  else {
    $callback = FALSE;
    $access_arguments = array(1);
  }


  $items['node/%node/translate']['page callback'] = 'entity_translation_overview';
  $items['node/%node/translate']['page arguments'] = array('node', 1, $callback);
  $items['node/%node/translate']['access arguments'] = $access_arguments;
  $items['node/%node/translate']['access callback'] = 'entity_translation_node_tab_access';
  $items['node/%node/translate']['file'] = 'entity_translation.admin.inc';
  $items['node/%node/translate']['module'] = 'entity_translation';
}
```

In my custom module I tried overriding like this:

```
function my_module_node_menu_alter(&$items, $backup) {
  $items['node/%node/translate']['title'] = "My New Title";
  $items['node/%node/translate']['access callback'] = 'my_module_transaltion_access';

}

function my_module_transaltion_access(){
   // code for my permissions according to user roles. 
}
```

But I am not able to alter this menu item. Please suggest what is right way to do this ?

**UPDATE:**

```
function my_module_menu_alter(&$menu,&$items) {

   $items['node/%node/translate']['access callback'] = "my_module_transaltion_access";
}

function my_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  switch ($hook) {
    case 'menu_alter':

      // Move some of our hook implementations to the end of the list.
      $group = $implementations['my_module'];
      unset($implementations['my_module']);
      $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
      break;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  global $user;

  foreach ($router_item['page_arguments'] as $key => $argument) {
    if (is_object($argument) && in_array($router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type, array('link'))) {
      foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['#link']['path'] == 'node/%/translate') {
          if (add condition according to requirement) {
            unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this code I am able to unset Translate tab according to user roles. 
NOTE: "link" is my content type.

Answer (score 0):

Try hook_menu_alter() to alter the menu,  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.

Moreover, entity_translation_node_menu_alter() is not a hook and it is a function called from entity_translation_menu_alter().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see updated question. I did with menu_alter as well and entity_translation was having high priority but I made priority of my module high and weight of my module is 1000 but it still does not work.